# LocalDB connection string in Visual Studio 2017 - ProjectsV13 Vs MSSQLLocalDB?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, localdb

VisualStudio shows me a connection string like the following in my DB project properties:

```
Data Source=(localdb)\ProjectsV13;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False;Connect Timeout=30
```

When I look at MS' documentation is seems to always reference strings like `(localdb)\MSSQL` or `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB`- rather than `localdb\ProjectsV13`.

Is this an important difference or simply a case of copy-paste the string and get on with it? I have a code project and a DB project in my solution and I want to use localDB for debugging purposes.

Comment: Given that LocalDB [is a feature of SQL Express](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15) meant for development, why not use SQL Express directly? The reason you see `ProjectsV13` inside VS 2017 is that Visual Studio itself uses LocalDB, and that's its instance. Your own application when it runs, will use *it's* own instance.

Comment: [The linked doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15#start-localdb-and-connect-to-localdb) explains that `MSSQLLocalDB` is an instance owned by the current user. Applications can create [named instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15#create-and-connect-to-a-named-instance), which is what VS 2017 did with `ProjectsV13`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I figured since I don't have SQLExpress installed, if VS can do this for me, why not let it? I haven't used this in _years_ but I recall VS just automagically spins up a DB when you hit F5 to run the app in debugger?

Comment: VS installs SQL Server Express. What are you going to do with the deployed application though? Will you install SQL Server Express too? Do you need to use LocalDB's per-user feature or could you use a shared database for all applications on the server?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it is basically just to have a local DB on my dev machine - I literally need _any_ test DB my application can write to so I can verify my code and debug any issues. Our test environment has MSSQL on a DB server so this the "it works on my machine" step prior to that.